# Partially filled orders on btc-e

Tags: buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins, btce

I just started with btc-e however I seem to have a load of partially filled orders. What happens with these? Can I cancel them? and if so, how do I do that and what are the consequences? Some have a price tag of $100 so the chances they get filled are minimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel them in the `Your current active orders` section of the [Trade tab](https://btc-e.com/exchange) by clicking the cancel link under `Action`. The remainder of the order is taken off the books and you can place new orders using the funds which are returned to your balance.

Comment: Do you still lose the percentage cut for BTC-e?  Your answer does not completely address his question

Comment: Without looking into it in detail immediately, I would expect the percentage to be taken as a percentage at the time the order is filled and so to be a percentage of the partial fill.